# Element level local variables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have to collapse expand repeated elements, for that I tried to use local variables in template whose scope will be for ngFor.
I can do it in angular 1.x in following way. But I want to implement same in Angular 2.x

**Angular 1.x Implementation (It works)**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="expand=false" ng-click="expand=!expand">
  <div ng-if="!expand">Small text</div>
  <div ng-if="expand">Expanded text</div>
</div>
```

**Angular 2.x Implementation (Doesn't work)**

I tried to implement same in Angular2 using but it is giving error: *"No exportas for 'false'"*.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" #expand="false">
  <div *ngIf="!expand">Small text</div>
  <div *ngIf="expand">Expanded text</div>
</div>
```

What is the correct implementation for element level local variables in templates for Angular 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular 1 when you used `expand` it wasn't local variable for the template, it was a property created by `ng-init="expand=false"` on the local `$scope` for each `ngFor` item. Angular doesn't have an equivalent for local scopes and `ng-init` that you can use in a template.

If you want to control visibility for each item your only option is to define a property on an item being iterated:

```
items = [{value: 1}, {value: 2}, {value: 3}];

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span (click)="item.expand=!item.expand">
        show
        <span *ngIf="item.expand">{{item.value}}</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

#### Regarding template reference

When you use the construction like this in Angular:

```
#expand
```

It does create a local template variable `#expand`, however it's not pointing to the variable in the controller/class, but to `ElementRef`. If you use it like this:

```
#expand="false"
```

Angular expects to have a directive `false` to be bound to `#expand` template variable instead of `ElementRef` but since there is none it throws the error `"No exports for 'false'".`

Comment: I am  totally agree with your explanation. Thanks, is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: what issue? just don't use `#expand` template variable as I've shown in the beginning of the answer

Comment: Already tried, the value of expand is same through all ngFor elements. When I click on one element, it reflects on another too.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange, ah, yeah, it's because in Angular.js you had local scope for each `ngFor` item. There's no equivalent in Angular. The only option for your is to add the property `expand` to items shown in `ngFor` and update it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use click event to set values

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="expand=!expand">
  <div *ngIf="!expand">Small text</div>
  <div *ngIf="expand">Expanded text</div>
</div>

export class item {
  expand:boolean
}
```

Comment: variable expand is common for all items in ngfor.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange, what error are you getting with the above code?

Comment: the value of expand is same through all ngFor elements. When I click on one element, it reflects on another too

Comment: Please refer this : https://plnkr.co/edit/MOoLEtypgSNDdlEv5rs3?p=preview

Comment: @LaxmikantDange, then you need to have expand property in item to make it work.Please see updated answer